# Kubernetes Ingress looking for secret in wrong place

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have Keycloak Chart (https://codecentric.github.io/helm-charts). Where I configured ingress to look at my secret for certificates, but instead it is looking at wrong place:

```
W0830 15:05:12.330745       7 controller.go:1387] Error getting SSL certificate "default/tls-keycloak-czv9g": local SSL certificate default/tls-keycloak-czv9g was not found
```

Here is how Chart looks like:

```
keycloak:
  basepath: auth/
  username: admin
  password: password
  route:
    tls:
      enabled: true
  extraEnv: |
    - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
      value: "true"
    - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
      value: /keycloak/master-realm.json
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: >-
        -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
  extraVolumes: |
    - name: realm-secret
      secret:
        secretName: realm-secret
  extraVolumeMounts: |
    - name: realm-secret
      mountPath: "/keycloak/"
      readOnly: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "keycloak-issuer"
    path: /auth/?(.*)
    hosts:
      - keycloak.localtest.me
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - keycloak.localtest.me
        secretName: tls-keycloak-czv9g
```

That is what i see from console:

```
$ kubectl get secret
NAME                      TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-lbt48       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      22m
keycloak-admin-password   Opaque                                1      15m
keycloak-realm-secret     Opaque                                1      15m
tls-keycloak-czv9g        Opaque                                1      15m


$ kubectl describe secrets/tls-keycloak-czv9g
Name:         tls-keycloak-czv9g
Namespace:    default
Labels:       cert-manager.io/next-private-key=true
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
tls.key:  1704 bytes
```

Why ingress is looking wrong place?

Comment: Can you add logs from nginx ingress controller pods ?

Comment: Is this the full output of the cert? There should be one line with `tls.crt`, too like here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

Comment: @AndreasJägle ended up with this configs https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/kubernetes-keycloak/tree/master/keycloak/certs now I get certs, but Keycloak isn't startning...

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu reworked configs https://github.com/PavelDemyanenko/kubernetes-keycloak/tree/master/keycloak/certs..but now keycloak not starting(

Comment: Looks like you are creating the certificate on your own (as shown in the github repo) but also use the annotations on the ingress to leverage ingress-shim to generate certs. That might be a conflict. If you put annotations to the ingress and use a valid (existing) issuer, then no own Certificate custom resource would be needed. See https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/

Comment: @AndreasJägle tried it and both work, now facing other chalanges) Thank you)